# Meaning of "as" in this sentence

Tags: conjunctions

everyone, I'm reading an English novel and I found the next sentence:

> The person I'd once been vanished as I wrapped myself in white when
>   the dust rose into clouds.

I don't really understand what "as" means in this sentence, so the whole sentence doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Please check meanings of common words in an online dictionary before posting a question. If after consulting a dictionary, the meaning is still unclear tell us why. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/as

Answer (score 1):

It is a synonym for "while." The two events -- the person's vanishing and the wrapping in white -- are happening simultaneously. This use of "as" is pretty common, even in regular speech, but it can sometimes carry a more sophisticated tone like it does here.

Comment: It could also mean 'because' or 'since' in this context. It would be similar to saying "My car would not start as the battery was flat." I'm not saying that you're wrong, just that the given sentence is open to either interpretation.

Comment: @BoldBen good point. The author might be implying both simultaneity and causation!

Answer (score 1):

*As* here is a conjunction. What follows the conjunction is simultaneous to what came before. For instance, here is one meaning defined in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as):

> 5: while, when // "spilled the milk as she got up"

Without context, *as* can also be taken in a causal way, where the part before *as* happens because of the part following *as*:

> 7: for the reason that : because, since // "stayed home as she had no car"

So the person she once was vanished *when* she wrapped herself in white, the person she once was vanished *because* she wrapped herself in white, or both. Which it is would be a matter for interpretation, and go beyond the boundaries of English language and usage.